# Question about extension of homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose $A$ is homeomorphic to a 2-sphere in 3-dimensional Euclidean space. Since $A$ is a closed surface in 3-dimensional Euclidean space, I wonder if the interior of $A$ together with $A$ itself can be homeomorphic to 3-ball by extending the homeomorphism?

Comment: I think your problem is just a generalisation of this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2114817/show-that-the-closed-unit-ball-in-mathbbr2-is-homeomorphic-to-the-unit-2-s

Comment: @albpesc Sorry, but I can’t figure out the similarities between these two questions, I think that problem is just kind of identification topology which has nothing to do with extension of homeomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might come up with an approach. We can construct a counter example similar to Alexander horned sphere. As the horned sphere provided by Alexander is kind of adding some branches to the exterior of the ball for infinitely many times[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeTcO.jpg)

Following the similar idea, with a given 2-sphere, we can imagine forming our construction by pushing two fingers into the sphere to create two branches like the first step in the construction of the horned ball (Although it is called a ball, we can only consider the sphere as well). Then, by doing what Alexander did to the branches we have constructed “inside” the ball by adding infinite “hooked” branches, we can get a 2 dimensional surface homeomorphic to a 2-sphere. Then we will show that the homeomorphism we want doesn’t hold in this case.

Consider the loop L which in our construction is kind of the loop inside the ball[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhEm7.jpg)
    We can deduce that the loop can’t be deformed to a point in the interior of the ball same as the original argument provided by Alexander. So the interior is not simply connected, hence it is not homeomorphic to 3-ball.

This is just an approach. I’m not sure if it is right.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the way, if mine is true,then we can construct a counter example that neither of the connected components will be simply connected by adding "inside" and "outside" branches to the sphere.